# Create excel graph with epplus

Tags: c#, excel, charts, epplus

here is what I have. I have an excel sheet with two column.
Column 1 had descriptions for legend, like Category1 Category 2 etc.
Column 2 has numbers with total count like 6,4,18 etc.

| Category | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Category1 | 6 |
| Category2 | 4 |
| Category3 | 18 |

I need to display a graph with the count values and display the category names for each line.
I tried different values but I cannot figure it out.
Here is my current code

```
        ExcelChart ec = (ExcelLineChart)chartSheet.Drawings.AddChart("chart_1",      
                        eChartType.Line);
            ec.SetPosition(1, 0, 3, 0);
            ec.SetSize(800, 300);
            var ran1 = chartSheet.Cells["A4:A6"];
            var ran2 = workSheet.Cells["0:0"];

            var serie1 = (ExcelChartSerie)ec.Series.Add(ran1, ran2);
            serie1.Header = chartSheet.Cells["A3"].Value.ToString();

            ran1 = chartSheet.Cells["B4:B6"];
            var serie2 = ec.Series.Add(ran1, ran2);
            serie2.Header = chartSheet.Cells["B3"].Value.ToString();

            var xml = ec.ChartXml;
            var lst = xml.GetElementsByTagName("c:lineChart");
            foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode item in lst[0].ChildNodes) {
                if (item.Name.Equals("ser")) {
                    foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode subitem in item.ChildNodes) {
                        if (subitem.Name.Equals("c:cat")) {
                            item.RemoveChild(subitem);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

This gives me a line with counts, but does not display the category names like I wanted.

Thanks in advance for any response.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nevermind, I fiddled around a little bit and found the answer

Here is the working code

```
ExcelChart chart = chartSheet.Drawings.AddChart("FindingsChart",
OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.Chart.eChartType.ColumnClustered);
chart.Title.Text = "Category Chart";
chart.SetPosition(1, 0, 3, 0);
chart.SetSize(800, 300);
var ser1 = (ExcelChartSerie)(chart.Series.Add(workSheet.Cells["B4:B6"],
workSheet.Cells["A4:A6"]));
ser1.Header = "Category";
```

Comment: how to create series from "Y values" and use (0, 1, ..., N) as "X values"?