# Create Chart in Excel using EPPLUS in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, epplus

I am using EPPLUS library and tried to draw Pie chart. when opening downloaded excel i am not getting any data or range selection in Chart area. Chart showing only single text which is title of the chart. My code is:

```
public static string RunSample5(DirectoryInfo outputDir)
    {
        FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(outputDir.FullName + @"\sample5.xlsx");
        if (newFile.Exists)
        {
            newFile.Delete();  // ensures we create a new workbook
            newFile = new FileInfo(outputDir.FullName + @"\sample5.xlsx");
        }
        using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
        {
            //Open worksheet 1
            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
            worksheet.InsertRow(5, 2);
             //Add the headers
            worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "ID";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Product";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 3].Value = "Quantity";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 4].Value = "Price";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 5].Value = "Value";

            //Add some items...
            worksheet.Cells["A2"].Value = 12001;
            worksheet.Cells["B2"].Value = "Nails";
            worksheet.Cells["C2"].Value = 37;
            worksheet.Cells["D2"].Value = 3.99;

            worksheet.Cells["A3"].Value = 12002;
            worksheet.Cells["B3"].Value = "Hammer";
            worksheet.Cells["C3"].Value = 5;
            worksheet.Cells["D3"].Value = 12.10;

            var chart = (worksheet.Drawings.AddChart("PieChart", eChartType.Pie3D) as ExcelPieChart);

            chart.Title.Text = "Total";
            //From row 1 colum 5 with five pixels offset
            chart.SetPosition(0, 0, 5, 5);
            chart.SetSize(600, 300);

            ExcelAddress valueAddress = new ExcelAddress(2, 3, 6, 3);
            var ser = (chart.Series.Add(valueAddress.Address, "B2:B3") as ExcelPieChartSerie);
            chart.DataLabel.ShowCategory = true;
            chart.DataLabel.ShowPercent = true;

            chart.Legend.Border.LineStyle = eLineStyle.Solid;
            chart.Legend.Border.Fill.Style = eFillStyle.SolidFill;
            chart.Legend.Border.Fill.Color = Color.DarkBlue;
            worksheet.View.PageLayoutView = false;
            package.Save();
        }

        return newFile.FullName;
    }
```

Comment: Refer this link. Hope this will help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29976752/create-excel-graph-with-epplus

Comment: Looks ok to me.  Maybe post a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Your call to chart.Series.Add() needs to take two ExcelRange values, the first for the values, the second for the category keys.

Here's an snippet that works for me:

```
chart.Series.Add(ExcelRange.GetAddress(dataRowStart, dataValueColumn, dataRowEnd, dataValueColumn), ExcelRange.GetAddress(dataRowStart, dataCategoryColumn, dataRowEnd, dataCategoryColumn));
```

Where dataRowStart, dataValueColumn, dataRowEnd, dataCategoryColumn are all local integer variables that are dependent on the data source.

Additionally, the ExcelRanges should not include the header rows.

Here is a link to an EPPlus example c# file on github that includes presently supported charts. 
https://github.com/pruiz/EPPlus/blob/master/SampleApp/Sample6.cs

Comment: How to define series for Y column only (I want X as 0,1,...,N)?