# Datetime format issue in X-Axis labels while exporting chart using EPplus

Tags: c#, excel, wpf, epplus, excel-charts

I am Exporting graph into an Excel sheet using EPPlus library but date format in X-Axis label are displaying in wrong dates format. Due to this problem graphs are not representing in the correct way.

On X-axis has date and time and Y-axis has a number. I want to display X-axis labels are dd-mm-yy hh:mm: ss format with actual data. I have tried to give the format of X-axis but still, it is not resolved. I have attached a screenshot of that chart and data. [image: Screenshot that chart and data]

How Can I display correct DateTime in X-axis label instead of a random date?

Below is a code which I have tried so far:

```
 ExcelWorksheet objWorksheet = obj ExcelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(dsItem.DataSetName);
                        objWorksheet.Cells.Style.Font.SetFromFont(new System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 10));
                        objWorksheet.Cells.AutoFitColumns();
                        objWorksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = dsItem.DataSetName;
                        objWorksheet.Cells[1, 1, 1, 8].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;

                        objWorksheet.Cells[1,1,1,8].Merge=true;
                        objWorksheet.Cells[1,1,1,8].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.LightGray);
                        objWorksheet.Cells[1,1,1,8].Style.Font.Bold = true;
                        objWorksheet.Cells[1,1,1,8].Style.Font.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
                        objWorksheet.Cells[1,1,1,8].Style.Font.Size = 12;
                                objWorksheet.Column(23).Style.Numberformat.Format = "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss";


var chart = objWorksheet.Drawings.AddChart(dsItem.DataSetName + i, eChartType.XYScatterLines); 
  DataView view = new DataView(item);


      DataTable distinctMeasNumber = view.ToTable(true, CommonEnum.CommonColumnName.Name.ToString());

                                foreach (DataRow dtItemRow in distinctMeasNumber.Rows)
                                {
    chart.Series.Add(ExcelRange.GetAddress(startIndex, 24, endIndex, 24), ExcelCellBase.GetAddress(startIndex, 23, endIndex, 23)).Header = dtItemRow[CommonEnum.CommonColumnName.Name.ToString()].ToString();
}
    chart.XAxis.Format = "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss";
```

Comment: Please show some of your code of what you tried so far.

Comment: I have updated question. This is the code of which I have tried.

Comment: Can you show the code where you initialize the chart and set the values for the x-axis?

Comment: var chart = objWorksheet.Drawings.AddChart(dsItem.DataSetName + i, eChartType.XYScatterLines);                                     chart.Series.Add(ExcelRange.GetAddress(startIndex, 24, endIndex, 24), ExcelCellBase.GetAddress(startIndex, 23, endIndex, 23)).Header = dtItemRow[CommonEnum.CommonColumnName.Name.ToString()].ToString();

Comment: You can take example from this link: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29976752/create-excel-graph-with-epplus

Comment: It seems like you are including the first row of your table. You should only include the actual dates. So something like `startIndex + 1`

Comment: Also if you have multiple series you want to add to your chart, you need to always use the same range for the `XSeries` part of your series.

Comment: No, I am not including the same row, above code is in a loop for each series.

Comment: Are you should those date-times are actually stored as date-time and not as `string`?  Your format is `"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"` but the image shows as `"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss"`.  I.e. the date part is using `/` as the separator in columns shown in the image when we would expect `-`.  I suggest you post a more complete code or try to write a unit test.